# How to redirect broken links using htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo, google-search-console

One of my site has 20 broken links showing in the webmaster tools. The problem is I have changed the design of the website and updated all the content after changing the design and the url's also got changed. In the webmaster tools it is showing the broken links of the old url's before I have redesigned the website. My question is do I need to redirect all those broken links to home page ?

Comment: by using .htaccess file you can achieve your goal.

Answer (score 3):

Try **ErrorDocument** in your **.htaccess** for redirect.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```